# Expected bool but has different type

Tags: f#

In the following method, I get the following error: `error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type bool but here has type Outcome list * ProbTree -> bool` when trying to call isSample in the if expression. I have no clue why I get the message.

isSample(os, t) is currently of type `'a * 'b -> Outcome list * ProbTree -> bool`. Any ideas? What I don't understand is why it expects type `bool` all of a sudden.

```
let rec isSample(os, t) = function
| ([], Branch(_, p, b1, b2))                         -> false
| (os, Branch(_, p, b1, b2)) when List.length os = 1 -> true 
| (h::t, Branch(_, p, b1, b2)) ->
    if h = S then isSample(t, b1) else isSample(t, b2) //This is where I get the error
| _ -> false


type Outcome  = | S | F 
type Sample   = Outcome list
type ProbTree = | Branch of string * float * ProbTree * ProbTree
                | Leaf of string
```

Comment: What is the first `'a * 'b` parameter for? It looks like you intend to match directly on one input pair so you should change the first line to `let rec isSample = function ...`

Comment: Yeah, that seems to remove the error. Is it because adding the parameters to the first line makes it expect them twice or something? I'm not entirely sure what the effects of it are.

Comment: `let rec isSample (os, t) = function | ...` is short for `let rec isSample (os, t) x = match x with | ...` so you are declaring a function with two arguments. You aren't using the first pair anywhere and only supplying one argument in the recursive calls. The compiler has inferred the return type should be `bool` since you return `true` and `false` in previous branches but your recursive calls return a function with one argument, hence the type error.